# WMS layer doesnot return data after filtering in open layer

Tags: openlayers, gis, geoserver

following are my source code. when i add a layer in wms its works perfectly, but when i filter the wms data my wms layer data is not visible on map. Please help if anyone have idea what wrong i am doing to get data from geoserver

```
> tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
>                 "Tiled",
>                 "http://apq.rsip.com:8080/geoserver/test/wms",
>                 {
>                     map: 'http://apq.rsip.com:8080/geoserver/test/wms',
>                     transparent: 'TRUE',
>                     layers: 'test:TABLEPOLY',                 
>                   transparent: 'true',                    
>                   projection: 'EPSG:4326'                                 
>                   }              
>               );  
> 
> 
>  var LINE = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
>                 "Tiled",
>                 "http://apq.rsip.com:8080/geoserver/test/wms",
>                 {
>                     map: 'http:/apq.rsip.com:8080/geoserver/test/wms',
>                     transparent: 'TRUE',
>                     layers: 'test:TABLELINE',                 
>                   transparent: 'true',                    
>                   projection: 'EPSG:4326'                                 
>                   }              
>               );   map.addLayers([osm, tiled]);   
>          tiled.mergeNewParams({'CQL_FILTER': "Time_UID LIKE '20150709%2A' "});
> tiled.redraw();
```

Comment: Maybe none of the features matches your filter.  Look in the log file to see the actual query

Comment: I've found that case can/does? matter in terms of the field names that are queried against.